# Counting number of unique names

Tags: sql, count

I'm trying to return a given number of server names and then a count of how many came back. For instance:

```
select servername, count(distinct servername) number
from TABLE
where [target] = 'blah'
group by servername
```

This returns the following:

```
servername      number
server1         1
server2         1
```

What I'm attempting to get is for the "number" column to read "2," because there are 2 distinct servernames. This should be incredibly simple, but I'm completely at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select distinct servername, 
  (select count(distinct servername) 
   from yourtable
   where target = 'blah') number
from yourtable
where target = 'blah'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f65f3/2)

Comment: I figured it would be something simple that I was overlooking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select servername, 
       count(*) over (partition by servername) as number
from the_table
where [target] = 'blah'
```

Window functions (the `over()` part) are supported by all modern DBMS including SQL Server (which you seem to be using)

Comment: I don't think you can use `count(distinct)` with an `over` in SQL Server.

Comment: @bluefeet: yes I realized that afterward. I corrected it (it is actually not necessary due to the `partition by`)